# How to change string encoding after reading it from file using default encoding?

Tags: c#, .net, encoding

I want to read text file which includes information about its encoding in its content. I don't know what encoding is used before I read the file. I use `System.IO.File.ReadAllText` for reading the file. How can I convert encoding without reading the file again?

I was trying to specify default encoding while reading the file and then converting it to final encoding, but it doesn't convert correctly:

```
string input = File.ReadAllText(filePath, Encoding.Default);
Encoding encoding = GetEncodingFromInput(input);
input = encoding.GetString(Encoding.Convert(Encoding.Default, encoding, Encoding.Default.GetBytes(input)));
```

Converted string doesn't contain the same characters as when it was read with correct encoding. Some characters are changed to question marks.

Comment: Don't. You can't recover text that was lost due to a wrong encoding. Use the *correct* encoding from the beginning, or don't specify one. ReadAllText will try to detect whether the file is UTF8/UTF16 and fall back to `Default`, ie the system's locale, if it can't

Comment: @Governor Note: `Encoding.Default` doesn't do what you seem to think it does... `Encoding.Default` is in fact specifying ANSI encoding for the current code page, which is a legacy encoding.

Comment: @MatthewWatson Not true [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=netframework-4.8) article states that Encoding.Default is "The default encoding for this .NET implementation" but also states that "Different computers can use different encodings as the default, and the default encoding can change on a single computer"

Comment: I recommend you just read the file as `Encoding.Unicode`. 1st of all it is the C# standard ([source](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/base-types/character-encoding) for this claim), and 2nd of all it is backwards compatible with ASCII and ANSI. So even if the file is encoded as ASCII or ANSI you will still read the right letters with Unicode

Comment: @MindSwipe I'm assuming that this the .Net Framework rather than .Net Core, in which case it will be an ANSI encoding. (.Net Core will always use UTF8)

Comment: @MindSwipe `Encoding.Unicode` actually refers to UTF-16 - and it will choke on a UTF-8 file. (Blame Microsoft, for a long time they referred to UCS-2 and UTF-16 simply as "Unicode", even in Win32 documentation)

Comment: @MindSwipe in other words, `Encoding.Default` is the codepage of the system's locale. Try *without* an encoding *first*. If you can't you'll have to try multiple encodings until you find those that don't mangle the text. One of them *may* or *may not* be the correct one

Comment: @MindSwipe `I recommend you just read the file as Encoding.Unicode` - You mean UTF8, not Unicode. Encoding.Unicode is a 2-byte encoding which is not compatible with ASCII. Anyway, if you omit the encoding from the call altogether, it uses the BOM to determine the encoding, if present, otherwise it defaults to UTF8.

Comment: Once a character is converted to `?` or `�` (meaning that the character is unknown in the current encoding), you cannot get the original one back (without reloading with the correct encoding).

Comment: Probably I don't understand how encoding works, but if I read string from file with incorrect encoding, can't I use the same encoding to convert string back to exactly the same bytes and get string from those bytes again using the correct encoding this time? It works with `Encoding.Default` (which is `ISO-8859-2` in my case), but for some other encodings it doesn't. File encoding is `IBM437`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes` to read the file, and then de-encode the byte array after you know which encoding you need, using something like: `System.Text.Encoding.XXXX.GetString()`

Comment: Thanks, but that's what I was trying to avoid.

Comment: @Governor you can't. `?` are error characters which means the *original* characters are simply gone.

Comment: @Governor I don't know if i got you wrong, it looked like you wanted to avoid physically reading the file twice. You can do a single read using ReadAllBytes, and then Convert the Byte array once, check which encoding you need, and then convert it again from the original byte array which is still in memory. If you don't want to convert the whole thing twice, probably check the other answer by  Dai

Answer (score 4):

> I don't know what encoding is used before I read the file.

Usually files that self-declare their encoding somehow have a documented technique or method for finding it - check your file format's published documentation.

If not, here's a few common techniques:

1. Look for a Unicode BOM in the first few bytes. You can do this by first reading the first 5 bytes from the file into a buffer (or 64-bit integer) and looking them up in a dictionary. This is what `System.IO.StreamReader` does by default.

   - You can see a list of known BOM byte sequences here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark
   - Note that UTF-8 does not have a BOM - but many editors (well, just Visual Studio) will stick `0xEF 0xBB 0xBF` at the beginning).
2. If it's a `text/*`-family of file-formats, with the encoding declared in some kind of header then you can read the first kilobyte of the file into a buffer and interpret every consecutive byte valued under `0x7F` as a character in an ASCII string, then use a simple parser (even `String.IndexOf`) or a Regex to look for your header's delimiter.

   - This technique is often used for HTML files where the HTTP header declaring the encoding isn't available and the program needs to look for `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" />` to get the encoding name.

> I use System.IO.File.ReadAllText for reading the file. How can I convert encoding without reading the file again?

You don't. Only use `ReadAllText` for simple `text/plain` files with consistent and known encoding - for this scenario else you'll need to use `Stream` and `StreamReader` (and possibly `BinaryReader`) together.

Comment: ReadAllText tries to detect the encoding from the BOM and falls back to Default. Even with the other classes one needs to know the encoding in advance

Comment: It's `SIE` format file and documentation says that currently it permits only `IBM Extended 8-bit ASCII` encoding, but it can be changed in the future and I wanted to handle this possibility. I think I will have to use this one and believe it's always the correct one.

Comment: @Governor  `IBM Extended 8-bit ASCII` is the 437 codepage. Use `Encoding.GetEncoding(437)`.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I know that and that's what I've been doing so far.

Comment: @Governor in that case the actual question should be how to detect a file's encoding, not how to convert encodings.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: I wanted to have possibility of using different encodings in the same file when finding information about new encoding further in the file. I wanted to read file in some default encoding and then decode some text values using specific encoding. If I detect file encoding, I lose this information.

Comment: @Governor Christoph already explained how to do that. Load the bytes then try the encodings. That's *fewer* steps than what you describe.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos: Ok, but reading bytes wouldn't be elegant solution in my case. Isn't .NET always using `Encoding.Unicode` for strings? I think I can use unicode to load file to string and then process it. Tags don't neet correct encoding, because it's always english letters. Then I can convert specific text values to final encoding when reading them. I think I can convert unicode string back to bytes and then convert it back to string using correct encoding. It works in my case, but I'm not sure if it will always work for any characters.

Comment: @Governor how is that more elegant than *not* having to convert back and using the same buffer in all cases? Instead of 1 buffer and 1-N strings you'll need N buffers and N strings. If you could use Unicode for that file you wouldn't need to specify *any* encoding. I already explained it, and I even posted links to the source code that show that calling ReadAllText without an Encoding tries to detect the Unicode encoding and falls back to UTF8

Answer (score 1):

From various comments it appears the text is in the `IBM Extended 8-bit ASCII` codepage, also known as 437. To load files in that codepage use `Encoding.GetEncoding(437)`, eg :

```
var cp437=Encoding.GetEncoding(437);
var input = File.ReadAllText(filePath, cp437);
```

The `?` or `�` characters are the conversion error replacement characters returned when trying to read text using the wrong codepage. It's not possible to recover the original text from them.

[Encoding.Default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=netframework-4.8#the-default-property-in-the-net-framework) is the system's default codepage, not some .NET-wide default. As the docs say:

> The Default property in the .NET Framework
>   In the .NET Framework on the Windows desktop, the Default property always gets the system's active code page and creates a Encoding object that corresponds to it. The active code page may be an ANSI code page, which includes the ASCII character set along with additional characters that vary by code page. Because all Default encodings based on ANSI code pages lose data, consider using the Encoding.UTF8 encoding instead. UTF-8 is often identical in the U+00 to U+7F range, but can encode characters outside the ASCII range without loss.

Finally, both [File.ReadAllText](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.readalltext?view=netframework-4.8#System_IO_File_ReadAllText_System_String_) *and* the [StreamReader](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#mscorlib/system/io/streamreader.cs,133) class it uses will try to detect the encoding from the file's BOM (Byte Order Marks) and fall back to UTF8 if no BOM is found.

**Detecting codepages**

There's no reliable way to detect the encoding as many codepages may use the same bytes. One can only identify *bad* matches reliably because the resulting text will contain `�`

What one can do is load the file's bytes once and try multiple encodings, eliminating those that contain `�`. Another step would be to check for expected *non-English* words or characters and eliminate the encodings that don't produce them.

[Encoding.GetEncodings()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.getencodings?view=netframework-4.8) will return all registered encodings. A rough method that finds probable encodings could be :

```
IEnumerable<Encoding> DetectEncodings(byte[] buffer)
{
    var candidates=from enc in Encoding.GetEncodings()
                   let text=enc.GetString(byte)
                   where !text.Contains('�')
                   select enc;
   return candidates;
}
```

or, using value tuples :

```
IEnumerable<(Encoding,string)> DetectEncodings(byte[] buffer)
{
    var candidates=from enc in Encoding.GetEncodings()
                   let text=enc.GetString(byte)
                   where !text.Contains('�')
                   select (enc,text);
   return candidates;
}
```